# How to reuse usercontrols accrossdifferent WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a WPF project say Application 1 and inside of it a user control is defined ..I want to resue this user control in another WPF project ,How I will be able to do it??

Both projects are binded into same source control

Answer (score 1):

best way is:

> define your user control in other project only contains your user control as Class library project (Like Scott Say)

but stil you can do this manually with these steps:

1. copy your user control from App1-pro(from solution explorer)
   to App2-pro(even you can don this
   from vs to another vs)
2. open Code
   behind file and go to Ctor and find
   InitializeComponent-mthod push
   f12(or use goto definition from
   right-click menu)
3. change the name
   space from `application1` to
   `Application2 namespace`(oops save
   it!)
4. change cod-behind-file
   namespace like above step(also save
   it)
5. go to xaml file and change
   this
   `x:Class=WpfApplication1.UserControl` to     `x:Class=WpfApplication2.UserControl`

Now enjoy your User-control!

Comment: Are you meaning to copy the contents of same user control in another project I am afraid I dont want to achieve this

Comment: no I mean to copy that file from VS (select Hole file from solution explorer)  &)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but let me try. Ensure that your user control is accessible from another project, i.e. there is a reference to the library where this control is defined. Then, at the place where you want this control to be reused, you need to define the namespace and use your control as any other controls. e.g.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="600"
...
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MySolution.MyPresentation.MyControls;assembly=MySolution.MyPresentation" 
/*controls namespace and assembly*/
>    
   <Grid>
        <userControls:ReusableControl
        /*particular properties of ReusableControl */
        />
   </Grid>    
<window>
```

Comment: My question was regarding User Control in WPF not custom control can I use the above snippet in case of User control as well

Comment: Sorry for that. You can definitely try, there shouldn't be much of the difference.

Comment: @Anindita Bhattacharyya I updated the code snippet to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your control into a seperate windows library (dll), and then add that dll to the references for each project.

Comment: Application 1 is building as exe not dll that is existent in our project from a long time I cannot modify that..

Comment: I am creating one more standalone WPF exe where I need to retain some user control as defined in Application 1 to have same look and feel